# Facebook get page publish token not working

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-page

We've been using this link for years to get a token so we can publish on facebook pages on behalf of the user:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=token&scope=pages_manage_posts&client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXX

[image]

But now it won't return to our page after selecting the pages to grant access to. All we get is a facebook page saying "This content is not available right now".

[image]

It stopped working mid september I think. Did FB change something?

Comment: So, to be clear - you get this error _after_ the login dialog asked you to select the pages you want to grant access to? Or is the login dialog call itself already showing this error, before the user can even do anything?

Comment: No, it's after. When I click "Proceed" to return to the site. @CBroe

Comment: Which button is supposed to be "proceed" now? Please set your language to English, before you take such screenshots, so that we don't have to deal with non-English content here.

Comment: Ok.. It's the right one.. The left one (edit settings) is to select which pages will be granted access to. @CBroe

Comment: Try and have the user completely remove the app from their settings, and then log in again - sometimes that can help fixes glitches.